# Why will a background image not show up?

Tags: image

[image: It shows up on the side but not on screen!]

Can someone please help me thanks!
https://www.the-blueprints.com/blueprints/modernplanes/boeing/19885/view/boeing_747-300/
this is where I got the image from

Comment: background images only appear in ortho views (numpad + 1, 3, 7 or ctrl to the opposite view)

Comment: you confused me do what?

Comment: @JustinH Please accept the answer that helped you as the answer to your question.

Comment: Alright so I went to right view then added a cylinder how do I make the cylinder longer / wider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background images are only visible in **Camera View** or in the **Preset Ortho views** along an axis.

- <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> for camera view
- <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> : shifts between ortho and perspective view
- <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> : front view
- <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> : right view
- <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> : top view
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> : back view
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> : left view
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> : bottom view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Background images only show up in camera view or on your Top, Bottom, Left... etc views, and you also have to be in orthographic mode.  To see the background image you need to switch to one of those views, and then switch to ortho mode by pressing 5 on the numpad or by pressing View Pers/Ortho in the view menu.

[image]